# Javascript AJAX Send a web request and print response?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

So basically I have a form with two option select inputs. Onchange of each of these form option selects I would like to call this AJAX function that would then send a web request to my python flask script which then would return the price and stock.

The output of my web API (python script) is like so price:stock so for instance 0.5:1000

So essentially I would like this AJAX function to send a request to my script getPrices to fetch the price:stock, then I would like to update my form with this information (I have two input boxes one for Price and another for stock).

How might I go about doing this? I am mainly into Python and Flask but it's come to my attention that AJAX is the way to go to do this.

My code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript>
        function getPrices(data)
        //ajax
        return data;
</script>


{% extends "_base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
<h3 class="text-center">Welcome {{current_user.email}}!</h3>
{% else %}
<h3 class="text-center">Price List</h3>
{% endif %}
<br>
<div class="form-group">
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="input-group mb-3-center" style="display: flex;justify-content: center;">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <label for="inputsm">Country</label>
    <br>
    <select class="selectpicker" title="Choose a country..." data-live-search="true" id="country" onchange="getPrices">
      <option value="uk">uk</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="inputsm">Service</label>
    <br>
    <select class="selectpicker" title="Choose a service..." data-live-search="true" id="service" onchange="getPrices">
      <option value="1">one</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="inputsm">Price</label>
    <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: medium;">$</span>
    <br>
    <label for="inputsm">Stock</label>
    <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size: medium;">-</span>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Also bare in mind, that both of these form selects need to be selected for this to run otherwise my script will return an error. In that case we can just not update the form.

Comment: AJAX *is* the way to do it but you don't need jQuery for it, in case you've inlcuded it for that purpose. The [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) would be your tool of choice. I'd consider sending the response from your Flask application back as JSON. It gives you more flexibility and clarity as you can add more data and name them.

Comment: You could also consider using the [Axios package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)